# What's the best way to say the noun "Objective" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

What's the best way to say "Objective" in Latin? As in, "Your next objective is to do [insert thing here]"?

Comment: I couldn't ever find an equivalent in latin for that. The closer I always got was "propositum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me humbly suggest *scopus*, "target".